# How can i call the thread itself?

Tags: java, multithreading

Lets say i am in the main method calling a process. Now if this process is stuck or taking too long, normally one can interupt it by interupting the thread.

But incase i have it implemented in the main method not in any external thread, how can i call that current thread itself for interuption like we call say thread.interupt();

Comment: I don't understand. What is your thread doing when you're trying to interrupt it?

Comment: I do not have any thread. I am reading the output from a Process using Runtime.exec and at times it can stuck for ever doing this. Normally we can prevent this forever wait by interupting the thread in which this process is executing. What im asking is, if this process is being executed in the main method and not inside any external thread, then how can i interupt this?

Comment: Main thread is also a thread, so you can interrupt it just like any other thread (use `Thread.currentThread()` to get reference to its thread object). To get an interrupt when stuck waiting on `Process.waitFor()` you will need an external timer thread that will be able to trigger the interrupt on main thread on timeout.

Answer (score 1):

Please back up a second. Thread.interrupt only interrupts wait conditions, not computations. There is no Java construct (except the monitoring/debugging agents) for interrupting a computation.

So, if you want a long-running computation to be interruptible, you have to write it to carefully check for interrupts every so often.

If you want to be able to 'interrupt' from outside the process altogether, you will need to handle signals. That's about the only interpretation I've been able to place on your question about the main thread.

[This blog post](http://twit88.com/blog/2008/02/06/java-signal-handling/) (not mine) has the basic information. From a handler, you could interrupt, for example, the main thread.

Comment: Re "There is no java construct for interrupting a computation", there is `Thread.stop(new InterruptedException())` but that has a lot of problems.

Comment: One of its problems is that it is deprecated, because of said problems. I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

You can let another thread interrupt "you" (main). Like this:

```
final Thread me = Thread.currentThread();
Thread wake_me_up = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //InterruptionException try catch omitted.
        Thread.sleep(200);
        me.interrupt();
    }
};

wake_me_up.start();

try{
    go_into_cave();
}catch(InterruptedException e){
    //I got interrupted
    System.out.println("thank you, you saved my life");
}

go_home();
```

While I find it hard to read...

Comment: You can also use `Timer` class: `new Timer().schedule(interruptTask, 200);` to get the same effect))

Answer (score 0):

In the main method, you'll have a reference to all Threads. Just get the right reference and do something like this

```
someThread.interrupt();
```

Make sure you don't forget to check if the Thread that is running got the flag to interrupt set true.
For example, in the middle of it's method, it needs to be checked if itself isInterrupted() by some Thread else

```
if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
doSomeStuff();
}
```

Comment: The someThread.interrupt(); happens to be the only thread in his program i.e the main method? How is he supposed to call this "someThread"?? This is what he is asking.

Comment: Well, I guess that if he set it to start running, so he got it's reference, and he can set the flag to interrupt. At least that's what I guessed.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Thread and call your process from inside the new Thread. Interrupt this thread and catch the exception as per your logic.

I am not sure how to do it only form within the main method, but if your process call is called through a method, just call this method from a new thread and put up a timer in the main method. Once the timer expires, interrupt that thread and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to kill the process, because it's hung, why are you even worrying about the thread? `Runtime.exec()` returns a `Process` object, which you can use to destroy the subprocess. You should be able to:

- Spawn the subprocess, saving the `Process` object.
- Presumably, you're reading the output stream of the process, via what is returned by
  `Process.getInputStream()`. So, continue to do that.
- However, spawn a *second* thread (or use the main thread) to monitor the process. If it
  decides that the process has run too long, it can kill it via `Process.destroy()`.
- At that point, the first thread should get an EOF or an `IOException` (stream closed) on
  the process's output stream.